# Executing Multiple Queries in Snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the Snowsight query editor.

I have a worksheet as a tile on a dashboard. Is it possible to execute all queries in the worksheet without clicking into the worksheet and highlighting all of the queries?

Comment: Doesn't the upper-right blue run button refresh the dashboards (i.e., run the queries behind the worksheet tile)? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately only opening up the tile and highlighting all statements to manually run will work. At this time when you use the dashboard level run button it only runs one query per tile - whichever was the last query ran.

(Confirmed with Snowsight PM)